# Update Maven Repository indices

Tags: android, repository, android-studio

Have a look at this snapshot and please HELP !!

[image]

[Snapshot URL](http://tinypic.com/r/155rss1/8)

I have downloaded this "nexus-maven-repository-index.gz " manually.But i am not able to figure out where to put it manually so that it stops downloading this file(bcoz its slow)
Please help me with this

P.S There is no folder namely ".m2" in my users directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not just a file you can download and drop somewhere. It unpacks the information in-place as it downloads and populates its index (which in my setup on MacOS is in my home directory under **Library/Caches/AndroidStudioPreview/Maven/Indices**). I'd recommend just letting it do its work.

Comment: Actually I did with it gradle...I downloaded it and placed it in .gradle folder. It worked so I thought there must be some way to sort this out.

Comment: Yeah, with Gradle, you can download things and put them in their cache directories if you know where things go, but Android Studio doesn't download this particular file and just drop it in the filesystem; it processes it as it downloads and generates its index.